# Open PIL Image in a folder outside directory of script

Tags: python, image, file-io, directory, python-imaging-library

I have a script.py located in a folder called subfolder1. This folder is inside a folder called mainfolder. There is another folder inside mainfolder called subfolder2. I would like for script.py to open an image inside subfolder2 and do some cropping etc, but I don't know how to get the directory right. I have tried:

```
import os
rel = "../subfolder2/1.bmp"
impath = os.path.abspath(rel)
im = Image.open(impath)
```

But the error message appears:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\mainfolder\\subfolder2\\1.bmp'
```

By the way, I am using Windows.

Comment: Is the path in the error message the path where the image is supposed to be?  Is the image file in fact there?

Comment: I was nice and still posted an answer, even though you haven't accepted any of them in the past. I hope this one fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your directory structure looks like this:

```
mainfolder/
    subfolder1/
        script.py
    subfolder2/
        1.bmp
```

... Then you can construct a path relative to the `script.py`. Right now you are only working with a path relative to the current working directly where you have launched your shell command.

You can do something like this:

```
import os
scriptDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
impath = os.path.join(scriptDir, '../subfolder2/1.bmp')
```

`__file__` is a builtin attribute in the module, that tells you the filesystem path of that module.

Comment: Nothing huh? Did this help you with your issue at all?